# Why does my while function not terminate?

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to write code for a tic-tac-toe game and I need the while loop to run until there are three Xs in a row. This is what I have

```
//This is the .hpp file with the function declaration and definition
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void playGameX(int x, int i, int j,char gameBoard[3][3]);
void playGameY(int x, int i, int j,char gameBoard[3][3]);
int gameWinAcross(char gameBoard[3][3]);


void playGameX(int x, int i, int j,char gameBoard[3][3]){
   cout<<"Player x, select a grid position (0 - 8):";
   cin>>x;
   if (x == 0){
       gameBoard[0][0] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   else if (x == 1){
       gameBoard[0][1] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 2){
       gameBoard[0][2] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 3){
       gameBoard[1][0] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 4){
       gameBoard[1][1] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 5){
       gameBoard[1][2] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 6){
       gameBoard[2][0] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 7){
       gameBoard[2][1] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 8){
       gameBoard[2][2] = 'x';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
}

void playGameY(int x, int i, int j,char gameBoard[3][3]){
   cout<<"Player o, select a grid position (0 - 8):";
   cin>>x;
   if (x == 0){
       gameBoard[0][0] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   else if (x == 1){
       gameBoard[0][1] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 2){
       gameBoard[0][2] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 3){
       gameBoard[1][0] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 4){
       gameBoard[1][1] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 5){
       gameBoard[1][2] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 6){
       gameBoard[2][0] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 7){
       gameBoard[2][1] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
   if (x == 8){
       gameBoard[2][2] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
}

int gameWinAcross(char gameBoard[3][3])
{
   int countx;
   int counto;
   for(int i=0;i<3; i++)
   {
       countx = 0;
       counto = 0;
       for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
       {
           if(gameBoard[i][j]=='x')
           {
               countx++;
           }
           /*else if(gameBoard[i][j]=='o')
           {
               counto++;
           }*/
       }
       if(countx == 3)
           return 1;
       //else if (counto == 3)
           //return 2;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

I have the while loop as part of the main.cpp separate the function that I wrote for checking the array

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToe_game_functions.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i,j;
    int x = 0;
    char gameBoard[3][3] = {{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'}};
    string user1,user2;//use string instead of char for multiple user entries

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter name:";
    cin>>user1;
    cout<<"You are player x"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter name:";
    cin>>user2;
    cout<<"You are player o";
    cout<<endl;

    while(gameWinAcross(gameBoard)!= 1){
        playGameX(x,i,j,gameBoard);
        gameWinAcross(gameBoard);
        playGameY(x,i,j,gameBoard);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

The issue that I have is that, even after I get a row with all Xs, the while loop keeps going.

Comment: What `while` loop?

Comment: And where's the `while` loop 

Comment: The `gameWinAcross` call in the body of the while loop does nothing.

Comment: You can shorten your code a LOT if you used the input to determine the square to be filled. Specifically, an input of x means that gameBoard[x/3][x%3]  should be changed. You can get rid of all the if-statements in your functions by doing this!

Comment: A function that displays the board would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code occurs here:

```
while(gameWinAcross(gameBoard)!= 1){
    playGameX(x,i,j,gameBoard);
    gameWinAcross(gameBoard);
    playGameY(x,i,j,gameBoard);
}
```

If X wins after the `playGameX(x, i, j, gameBoard);` execution, the next line won't actually do anything. This means that player X can make a winning move with nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the way you are calling the function to check if any player has won. It might happen that the **first line of your while loop returns 1** but **you haven't added any condition to break the loop**. Hence it might be going in infinite loop.

The correct code should be something like this -

```
while(1){  
    //first player will play    
    playGameX(x,i,j,gameBoard);
    //If the first player wins, output his name as winner and break the loop
    if(gameWinAcross(gameBoard)== 1){
        cout<<"\n** X wins\n";
        break;          
    }
    // now the second player will play
    playGameY(x,i,j,gameBoard);
    // if second player wins, output his name and declare him the winner and break from loop.
    if(gameWinAcross(gameBoard)== 1){
        cout<<"** Y wins\n";
        break;          
    }        
}
```

Hope this solution helps !

---

### Few small suggestions -

1. You can reduce your `PlayGameX` function and `PlayGameY` function codes by huge amount if you just do the following -

=>

```
void playGameY(int x, int i, int j,char gameBoard[3][3]){
   cout<<"Player o, select a grid position (0 - 8):";
   cin>>x;
   if (x >= 0 && x <= 8){
        int row = x/3, column = x%3;
       gameBoard[row][column] = 'o';
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               cout<<gameBoard[i][j]<<' ';
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }
   }
}
```

The same can be applied to `PlayGameX` as well.

2. Also, you have only checked for horizontal rows to declare winner. If you want to  declare winner based on 3 in a column or diagonal as well, then you can modify you code as below -

=>

```
//Here, char c is the player's symbol after whose turn we are checking for win
int gameWinAcross(char gameBoard[3][3],char c)
{  // Check for 3 chars in horizontal, vertical, and 2 diagonal direction for win
   int count_horizontal = 0 ,count_vertical = 0,count_diagonal = 0,count_diagonal2=0;
   for(int i=0;i<3; i++)
   {  
       // Checking diagonals
          if(gameBoard[i][i]==c)count_diagonal++;
          if(gameBoard[i][3-i]==c)count_diagonal2++;
       for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
       {   
           // Hortizontal direction check
           if(gameBoard[i][j]==c)
           {
               count_horizontal++;
           }
           // Vertical direction check
           if(gameBoard[j][i]==c)
           {
               count_vertical++;
           }
       }
       if(count_horizontal == 3 || count_vertical == 3 || count_diagonal == 3 || count_diagonal2 == 3)
           return 1;
   }
   
    return 0;
}
```